# How to override second instance of windows store app with the first instance of same windows store app

Tags: windows-store-apps

After running the my windows store app, i added some part of data of app at start page as secondary tile and again added different data to secondary tile.

I can able to loaded the first tile(might be a second one) with data from start up page,but when i loaded the second tile(might be a first one) , the data wasn't loaded.

Comment: It's not clear from your question what your issue actually is? Is the issue with multiple running instances of an app or with updating multiple tiles? Or something else? Can you show a simple example of what you're doing-not just a description?

Comment: multiple running instances of an app . means i run the first one , with out closing the first one, running the second , here i was getting the problem. data was not loading in the second one.while loading the second i don't need  to run the first one. the second one should override the first one.